# False Cache Sharing in Vector of Threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, pthreads

I'm trying to add the contents of a vector (**v**) using threads on another vector (**localSum**) as the following codes shows:

```
void threadsum(int threadID, int numThreads, const vector<double>& v, vector<double>& localSum)
{
        size_t start = threadID * v.size() / numThreads;
        size_t stop = (threadID + 1) * v.size() / numThreads;
        localSum[threadID] = 0.0;
        for (size_t i = start; i < stop; i++) {
            localSum[threadID] += v[i];
        }           
}
```

Right now, I'm having performance issues regarding the problem of false cache sharing, because every thread is trying to write on different places on the same cache line. The vector **v** and the vector of threads **localSum** are declared as follows:

```
// create the input vector v and put some values in v
        vector<double> v(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                v[i] = i;

        // this vector will contain the partial sum for each thread

        vector<double> localSum(numThreads, 0);
```

Now, how can I avoid having this problem?. One idea I got is to use mutex to restrict the timing of access to **localSum**. Other idea I have was maybe to missalign the elements of the vector so they won't be on the same cache line?. Any idea to solve this problem would be much appreciated!.

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236603/cache-lines-false-sharing-and-alignment

Comment: Thanks, but in that case he's working with an fixed array size, My idea is to work with vectors so the number of threads can increase.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the sum for each thread in a local variable, then save that out into `localSum` at the end of your loop.

```
size_t stop = (threadID + 1) * v.size() / numThreads;
double sum = 0.0;
for (size_t i = start; i < stop; i++) {
    sum += v[i];
}
localSum[threadID] = sum;
```

You'll still have that issue with cache line sharing, but you'll only be doing one write instead of N.  Also, with the loop in this form, the optimizer should be able to do a better job.

Comment: Wouldn't an optimizer be able to perform a similar optimization ?

Comment: @LWimsey Possibly.  If it needs to handle possible aliasing (where `v` and `localSum` refer to the same vector) it can't.  This solution doesn't depend on the optimizer, which is helpful for debug builds (where you don't optimize).

Comment: The thing is I'm using an optimizer, and v and LocalSum aren't refering to the same vector

Comment: @JmonkG But the compiler doesn't know that they aren't the same when it generates the code.  Usually it won't optimize out writes to memory that isn't function local, as there are too many ways for things to go wrong if it does.